# changing the type of variables when they are defined with Model.addVars() in Gurobi Python

Tags: python, types, var, gurobi

I have defined the variables as following:
`y = m.addVars(2,6, vtype= GRB.BINARY, name = 'y')`

Now I wish changing their type to GRB.CONTINUOUS.

How can I do it in a compact way?
I want to avoid repeting this line for all 12 variables:
 `y[0,0].VType = GRB.CONTINUOUS`

Thank you.
Best,
Paola

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over the values in the tupledict y:

```
for v in y.values():
  v.VType = GRB.CONTINUOUS
```